# Java Heap Space Error in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using Tomcat 7.0.28. I have deployed a war file.
In this war file there is a server like structure where we can upload the files.

Now when i access that web page it is working, but when i try to upload the large files it is showing error of JAVA Heap Space.

How can i solve it?

Comment: Set a higher heap size on startup may fix you problem.

Comment: One of the numerous answers about how to set the java heap space in tomcat : http://serverfault.com/questions/139435/where-to-set-java-heap-options-e-g-xmx-for-tomcat-6-under-ubuntu-9-04

Answer (score 6):

You are probably trying to put the whole file in memory. Your first shot should be to change the -Xmx parameter at the Tomcat JVM startup options to give it more memor. Aside from that, you'll have to read the file one chunk at a time, and write it on the hard drive, so as to free the memory.

Comment: @Vijay here's a link to [setting the Xmx paramter](http://serverfault.com/questions/139435/where-to-set-java-heap-options-e-g-xmx-for-tomcat-6-under-ubuntu-9-04). As to reading the file in chunks, how do you *currently* read the file?

Comment: actually i have setup BIM SERVER and they provided the WAR file for deployment. So don't know how they are reading files. but i did change the heap size using -Xmx attribute but still it is not working.

Comment: Increasing the heap size will not be useful -- go talk to the "BIM SERVER" folks and ask about their file-upload requirements. You could also configure your server to do a heap dump on OOME so you can look at what it taking up all the space: probably a huge byte array with the file's contents. If so, "BIM SERVER" is poorly-written.

Answer (score 4):

You can increase `HeapSize` in tomcat using below command .

**Linux :** Open **Catalina.sh** file placed in the "bin" directory. You have to apply the changes to this line

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m "
```

**Windows:**

Open the "**Catalina.bat**" file placed in the "bin" directory

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m
```

Restart the tomcat after above change.